# error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'sot'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am struggling with this two-line of code!
first I got this error that :
"error CS1929: 'AvatarTracking' does not contain a definition for 'GetOrAddComponent' and the best extension method overload 'UnityEngineExtensions.GetOrAddComponent(GameObject)' requires a receiver of type 'GameObject'"

then I changed the code from :

```
 StaticOffsetTransform sot = this.GetOrAddComponent<StaticOffsetTransform>();
```

to

```
StaticOffsetTransform sot;
sot = sot.gameObject.GetOrAddComponent<StaticOffsetTransform>();
```

and now I got this error that "error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'sot'"
please share your idea to solve this issue.

p.s: I even try these two:

```
StaticOffsetTransform sot = new GameObject.GetOrAddComponent<StaticOffsetTransform>();
StaticOffsetTransform sot = (Instantiate sot as GameObject).GetOrAddComponent<StaticOffsetTransform>();
```

but still doesn't work!

Comment: you are using `sot` before assigning it.

Comment: I've just edited the question. is it still the same reason? @DanielA.White

Comment: new GameObject() <= need to add "()" keyowrd

Comment: you can't redeclare a variable. ideally a variable should be only used for one thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on second line

```
StaticOffsetTransform sot;
sot = sot.gameObject.GetOrAddComponent<StaticOffsetTransform>();
      ^^^
```

You are using sot before initializing it (and you will get a null reference exception too)

To solve this you must check your logic of "how I get a instance of StaticOffsetTransform"

To solve the specific problem of CS0165 you must not use the variable before add a new reference to it or get the reference from another way like a method call, property, variable, etc.

A example of compliant code:

```
StaticOffsetTransform sot = components.GetOrAddComponent<StaticOffsetTransform>();
```

reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165